# Use GPU in Tensorflow.js on mobile device

Tags: ionic-framework, capacitor, tensorflow.js

I have been building hybrid app using Ionic/Angular with the capacitor plugin.
I code in Javascript.

I wanted to add my neural network classifier on it.
It requires 500x500 pixels image.
On computer with gen 2 nvidia GPU I have around 10 fps.

I was hoping to get 2 or 3 fps on recent mobile device but I wasn't able to use the computation power of the phone using TensorFlow.js.

How to use GPU for predictions in TensorFlow.js ?

In documentation, it's said that TensorFLow.js should automaticaly select GPU so I don't have to add any thing else to my code.

Also :
"TensorFlow.js executes operations on the GPU by running WebGL shader programs."

Is it not possible to use Capacitor + Tensorflow.js use full power of the GPU ?

Thank you very much for you help.